# Terminal command to run Java file with json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal, json-simple

I have a Java project where I am using json-simple-1.1.1.jar. I'm using IntelliJ and Maven to run my project and I'm using Windows. I set up my classpath for json-simple-1.1.1.jar in my environment variables and I set up the dependencies on IntelliJ. I can run the project just fine if I press the green run button in IntelliJ, but I want to know how to run it in IntelliJ's terminal.

Normally I run my Java file by going to my file's directory and doing a `javac MyFile.java`, but I know that I have to add something to the command. I've tried something like `javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar MyFile.java` while I'm in the directory of my file but it doesn't work and I keep getting this error `package org.json.simple does not exist`.

What terminal command do I use? My actual .jar file for json-simple isn't actually in my project, it's in a different folder in my computer. Would that be contributing to the problem?

Comment: Does it help to set full path to used jar?

Comment: How would I set the full path to the jar?

Comment: I meant to set full path in command line "javac -cp <PATH_TO_JAR>/json-simple-1.1.1.jar MyFile.java"